# Resource creation screen says my Azure subscription is disabled even though it's not

Tags: azure, resources, subscription

I'm trying to add a SQL Database to my resource group, but it says my subscription is disabled. However, when I go to my Azure subscription page, it says it's active. And my hosted web app loads successfully in the web browser, so that must mean my subscription really is active, right?

Why does the SQL Database creation screen say that my subscription is disabled? What can I do to fix this?

I should mention that my subscription actually was disabled this morning, but then I fixed it by changing my payment plan. However, that was several hours ago. Do I just need to keep waiting for my changes to take effect? Or is there some other action I'm supposed to take?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update: After waiting 24 hours, the error has gone away. I guess it just takes a long time to fully reactivate a subscription.